# Cannot resolve qTip API methods

Tags: knockout.js, qtip2

I am using qtip2. I am trying to access the qTip API object, but am not seeing any of the methods documented [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#methods). I am using qTip in conjunction with KnockoutJS, so my code looks like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withdocs = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var docs = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var nDocs = docs.length;
        console.log(docs);
        if (nDocs > 0) {
            var label = nDocs == 1 ? " doc" : " docs"; 
            $(element)
                .addClass('withdocs')
                .text("with " + docs.length + label)
                .qtip({
                    content: {
                        text: getTooltipText(docs),
                        title: {
                            text: 'Documents used in query'
                        }
                    }, 
                     show: {
                        event: 'mouseover',
                        solo: true // Only show one tooltip at a time
                     },
                     hide: 'unfocus',
                     style: {
                        classes: 'ui-tooltip-wiki ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow'
                     }
                })
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var docs = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        // error occurs in the following line
        $(element).qtip("api").updateContent(getTooltipText(docs));
    }
};
```

The error that is reported is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<QTip> has no method 'updateContent'
```

The full example can be found in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/BmwGJ/3/).

Am I using the wrong version of qtip? I am linking to [this one](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/packages/nightly/jquery.qtip.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are using qtip2 and the updateContent method was for qtip1. I have updated your code to work here.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/bANWb/

I had one issue with setting the content via a text selector, you need the prerender value to be true. Someone mentioned this gotcha here

http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/thread-solved-updatecontent-and-documentation-on-methods

Hope this helps

Comment: In my app, I need hundreds of these, which makes them somewhat inefficient to initialize; I moved the initialization to the mouseover handler in the init function which first tests for qtip & if not found creates it.